# How to fix jQuery function only works once. Must be related to ajax .load()

Tags: jquery, ajax

My jquery code works fine if the browser is fresh (newly refreshed). So basically it only works once. After that, the e.preventDefault() stopped working as well as the whole code.

Im thinking it maybe because of my .load ajax function.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.cart-remove').each(function() {
$(this).click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('.cart-drawer .loader-container').css('display','flex');
$.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    success: function(response) {
       $.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart) {
       $('.cart-count').html(cart.item_count);
});
      $('.cart-drawer').show();
      $('body').toggleClass('position-relative');
      $('.header-section').toggleClass('d-flex');
      $('.overlay').show();
      $('.cart-drawer').addClass('slideIn');
      $(".cart-drawer").load(" .cart-drawer > *");

    }
})
})
})
})
</script>
```

Comment: see console if it shows any error.

Comment: Can you post the HTML, if possible?

Comment: Sorry for late reply guys, No Error in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the each loop, delegate you click event

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click','.cart-remove',function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.cart-drawer .loader-container').css('display', 'flex');
      $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        success: function(response) {
          $.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart) {
            $('.cart-count').html(cart.item_count);
          });
          $('.cart-drawer').show();
          $('body').toggleClass('position-relative');
          $('.header-section').toggleClass('d-flex');
          $('.overlay').show();
          $('.cart-drawer').addClass('slideIn');
          $(".cart-drawer").load(" .cart-drawer > *");

        }
      })
    })
})
```